# RestKit w/ CoreData Saving the MOC Confusion

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

So I'm a little confused with how RestKit is suppose to work with CoreData. I am familiar with CoreData (however mostly I use MagicalRecord) and I am trying to learn RestKit but I'm confused with all the documentation out there what RestKit is suppose to handle. I have successfully loaded a NSManagedObject from a REST web service and I have this entity object but I'm not sure if I am suppose to handle the saving of this entity to my managed object context or is this something RestKit will do auto-magically. If the latter, can anyone point me in the right direction for utilizing such features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that YES it does do it Auto Magically. My real issue was that I was never setting the ObjectManager's persistant store even though I thought it was. Now when I use 'getObjects..' method everything works beautifully.